# How to make a radio app keep playing in the background of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an app that streams a radio station. The view contains a button, which after being pressed calls the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. (See screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4utv.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wrqL.png)).

The IBAction for the play button looks like:

```
- (IBAction)Play:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fm.radiokfor.com:8080"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];


    [self presentViewController:playercontroller animated:NO completion:nil];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];

}
```

My question is: is there a way so that I could play the stream without having the MPMoviePlayerController on top of the View and allow me to navigate to other tabs? Is it possible to play the audio in the background only by clicking on the button?

Comment: I would suggest you use [`AudioStreamer`](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) to stream the webradio. This will give you more freedom in the design of your view and not display the ugly `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Also the sample app has support from background playing.

Comment: Is there any sample how to integrate it because i'm having troubles incorporating it to my project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by using the following method:

```
- (IBAction)Play:(id)sender
{

    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fm.radiokfor.com:8080"]];
    [self.player play];
    self.radioStationLabel.text = @"Now playing: Radio KFOR";
}

- (IBAction)Stop:(id)sender
{

    [self.player pause];
    self.radioStationLabel.text = @"Press 'Play' to start stream";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one of the sanctioned [uibackgroundmodes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) under your app's info.plist.

Comment: i edited the info.plist file but the apps stops playing when not in background.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of *MPMoviePlayerViewController*.